# Fill whole screen with four buttons by two rows in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, height, width, android-gridlayout

I want to fill the whole screen with four buttons that has the same width and height so I thought a grid layout would be a great idea:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        />

</GridLayout>
```

Unfortunatly my result looks like this:

[image: GridLayout Results]

I don't understand why the height of the second row is so big?
I thought every cell in a grid layout got the same width and height!

Comment: update your image link. It doens't open

Comment: obviously because rowWeight are different

Comment: Try setting all rowWeights to **1**

Comment: yeah you are right it works but I dont really understand why shouldnt they be in a single row now? I thought I need two rows...

Comment: In facts, as you said, now it works. Meaning that you ended up with a perfectly divided 2x2 grid. And this is how weights work: they must be **even** with each other, if you want them to be evenly distributed. It was that easy. Wasn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can also be done with ConstraintLayout, which will give you a flat hierarchy and more flexibility for future changes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do that with Gridlayout :

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
</GridLayout>
```

you can do this with linearlayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The first solution is to be preferred, because of its **flatness**. The second one is **bad**. Because nested layouts result in poor performances.